# Flutter - How to give dynamic width to buttons in a row

Tags: flutter, dart

```
              AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            title: Text(
              'Job Added',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            content: Builder(builder: (context) {
              var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
              var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

              return SizedBox(
                height: height / 5,
                width: width,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Spacer(),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [

//// All three buttons take equal width, I don't want that

                        Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: Styles.greenElevatedButtonStyle,
                            onPressed: () => () {
                              Get.toNamed(Routes.jobList);
                            },
                            child: const Text('Job List'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Dimens.boxWidth10,
                        Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: Styles.yellowElevatedButtonStyle,
                            onPressed: () => () {
                              Get.toNamed(Routes.jobDetails);
                            },
                            child: const Text('View Job'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Dimens.boxWidth10,
                        Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: Styles.redElevatedButtonStyle,
                            onPressed: () => () {},
                            child: const Text(' Add New Job '),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
            actions: [],
          ),
```

I want that the buttons should take dynamic width according to the text. So the button that says "Add New Job" should be wider than the other 2; the text on the button shouldn't get wrapped, it should stay in a single line.

Comment: Just remove Expanded from all Elevated buttons.

Comment: + can you include full sample widget  like removing `Styles`...